# How to change this WP logo and posts url in block editor?

Tags: filters, block-editor

I want to know is there any filter to change WP Logo with some text and change it's URL?
[image]

Comment: Check this https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/adding-a-custom-dashboard-logo-in-wordpress-for-branding/

Answer (score 2):

You can change the logo in the block editor or site editor using the SlotFill system.

Have a look at the this example code taken from https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/main-dashboard-button/

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { __experimentalMainDashboardButton as MainDashboardButton } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
 
const MainDashboardButtonTest = () => (
    <MainDashboardButton>
        Custom main dashboard button content
    </MainDashboardButton>
);
 
registerPlugin( 'main-dashboard-button-test', {
    render: MainDashboardButtonTest,
} );
```